# How can I model the way that average Joe trades in FX markets?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, behavioral-finance

I want to develop a trading bot that trades like a non-professional trader in FX markets.
I wonder if it is possible to think that an average trader trades randomly regardless of the market conditions?
Or is there a behavioral model to model non-professional traders' trading activity?

Comment: This question is too general. You need to define more clearly what you mean by average Joe. There is a difference between 1mm unique (and distinct) average Joe's having a net and average impact, or 1mm of the same average Joe's generating the same net average impact. Otherwise explain what you mean by the difference between professional and non-professional trading activity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that they are trading randomly. You'd need some data to figure out what they tend to do to imitate it.

Or, you can build a repertoire of trades from books or forums and exploit knowledge from psychology to determine how the bot will choose between them.